# Linq function based on stored procedure which does count(*) returns null

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure which does a select count(*) ...
I have a LINQ function called GetCount() based on that SP.

When I do something like:
int? count = datacontext.GetCount().Single().Column1;

count is null. The SP never returns null.

Why is count null?

Comment: SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM    customers

it's very simple and it returns a number. I have tested it. Is my LINQ correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I gave an alias to the count.

Comment: Can you post your solution? Where did you define the alias?

Comment: It's SELECT COUNT(*) as CustCount FROM customers.

Comment: Indeed! That's quite surprising, I must say - almost sounds like a bug in the Linq-to-SQL code base......

Comment: It might be related to a bug we had in the designer that was fixed in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Linq-to-SQL doesn't like Stored Procs that return a single result as a SELECT statement. I had the same trouble you're seeing.

One solution for a case like this would be to create a stored function instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCountFunc()
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyCount INT

    SELECT @MyCount = COUNT(*) FROM Customers

    RETURN @MyCount
END
```

and then pull that into your Linq-to-SQL data context and reference it. In this case, I get back an INT no problem.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/04/10/linq-to-sql-returning-scalar-value-from-stored-procedure.aspx

basically if you are trying to return an int from a stored procedure it needs to look like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeCountRet]         

AS

BEGIN

  DECLARE @Ret INT

  SELECT @Ret = COUNT(*) FROM Emp

  RETURN @Ret

END
```